# JenkinsFile Clean Workspace not working in post function

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I am not able to clean the workspace with below Jenkinsfile its throwing below error please suggest, have tried delete directory Also it is also not working.

jenkins 2.162 version

```
Error :
Error when executing always post condition:
hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 255
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.handleExit(DurableTaskStep.java:569)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.check(DurableTaskStep.java:515)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.run(DurableTaskStep.java:461)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

```
pipeline 
{
agent any
}
tools {maven "maven3"}
stages 
{
stage("Build") 
{
steps 
{
sshagent(['bitbucketssh']) 
{
script 
{
sh "bash ./ciBuild.sh"
}
}
}
}
}
post 
{
always 
{
cucumber buildStatus: 'UNSTABLE',
failedFeaturesNumber: 1,
failedScenariosNumber: 1,
skippedStepsNumber: 1,
failedStepsNumber: 1,
sshagent(['bitbucketssh']) 
{
script 
{
sh "bash ./destroy.sh"
cleanWs()       /* clean workspace now working 
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the cleanWs() is not working, and you're not failing on the destroy.sh??? try putting it temporarily in command and see if it reaches the cleanWs command

Comment: The pipeline code you have provided doesnt seem to be correct when I indent the braces. Could you please have a look at providing a better formatted example?